# Android Jetpack Compose how to show a MP4 video as an animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I was given a task to show an animation for a couple of screens. I was given the animation as a mp4 file. From my understanding jetpack compose animations don't use MP4 file but rather drawable. I was wondering what is the correct approach to show an animation as a video or just show a video. Thank You for your time.

Comment: You can use Exoplayer which is the standard for implementing video playback on Android. https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html , as of now Exoplayer does not provide support for Jetpack compose so you'll have to create the Composeable yourself for the Exoplayer.

Comment: I did some research and exo player did come up, but the user wont be able to interact with the video, no sound will be played, its just a simple video that will look like an animation to the user. I wanted to see if their was another way of using a media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play MP4 videos using `ExoPlayer`. You can refer to the below example crafted by me.

**Example**

How to use exoplayer in `Jetpack Compose`. I have used exoplayer in one of my recent projects. so this may be helpful for you as well.

***gradle dependency***

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.7'
```

Composable Functions

```
@Composable
fun ExoplayerExample() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri("your-uri")
        .build()
    val exoPlayer = remember(context, mediaItem) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .also { exoPlayer ->
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
                exoPlayer.repeatMode = REPEAT_MODE_OFF
            }
    }

    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        })
    ) {
        onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
    }

    
}
```

this way you can use exoplayer in Jetpack Compose. You can customize it as per your requirement.

Comment: I would like to do this using Media3 dependency but StyledPlayerView doesn't get imported.

Comment: I dont have much control over the PlayerView. Is it possible to disable any user interaction with the video and also remove play and pause controls?

Comment: Yes of course. You can control all these things

Comment: @ChiragThummar Hi there i have a question. Actually i'm showing the list of videos in specific folder not want to play it just want to show thumbnails of videos and then user will click to watch it. For images i m using AsyncImage from coil what should i use to diplay thumbnails of videos ?

Comment: You can fetch Thumbnail from video like  https://gist.github.com/chiragthummar/ac3493e50e9a4fda222e937ac63dd85c

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VideoView` or `ExoPlayer` to play your animation video. But they're not available in Jetpack Compose yet. So, to include android views which're not available in Jetpack Compose, use the `AndroidView` composable. AndroidView is passed a lambda that returns a View. Here's the link for [AndroidView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose) example.

**Please note:** You have to handle Video playback with lifecycle changes.
If the video has a sound, that you don't want to play with it, remove the sound from your video.